# Getting response in desired format with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

There are a bunch of tables in my database named courses, topics, subtopics, assessments.
One course can have multiple topics. One topic can have multiple subtopics. One topic can have multiple assessments.
There is a query I'm trying to implement in which I need a response in a specific format. For which aggregation has been used. I'm getting the desired result except for assessments.
The format I want is an array of courses. For each course, there is an array of topics. For each topic, there is an array of subtopics. This much I'm able to achieve. Now, I want for each topic an array of assessments just like subtopics which I'm unable to achieve.

The Code:

```
      select courses.course_id as id, courses.course_name as name, courses.course_duration as 
      duration, courses.course_description as description,
      jsonb_agg(
          jsonb_build_object(
              'id',          topics.topic_id,
              'name',        topics.topic_name,
              'duration',    topics.topic_duration,
              'sequence_no',   topics.sequence_no,
              'description', topics.topic_description,
              'subtopics',   subtopic.subtopics,
              'assessment_id', assessments.id
          )
          order by topics.topic_id
      ) topics
      from courses 
      left join topics on courses.course_id = topics.course_id
      cross join lateral (
          select jsonb_agg(
              jsonb_build_object(
                  'id',   subtopics.subtopic_id,
                  'name', subtopics.subtopic_name,
                  'assignment_id', subtopics.assignment_id,
                  'homework_id', subtopics.homework_id,
                  'on_free_trial', subtopics.on_free_trial
              )
              order by subtopics.subtopic_id
          ) subtopics
          from subtopics
          where subtopics.topic_id = topics.topic_id
      ) subtopic
      left join assessments on assessments.topic_id = topics.topic_id
      cross join lateral (
          select jsonb_agg(
              jsonb_build_object(
                  'id',   assessments.id
              )
              order by assessments.id
          ) assessments
          from assessments
          where assessments.topic_id = topics.topic_id
      ) assessment
      group by courses.course_id 
      order by courses.course_id
```

The output is as follows:

```
        {
        "Response": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Data Structures and Algorithms",
                "duration": 32,
                "description": "A data structure is a named location that can be used to store and organize data. And, an algorithm is a collection of steps to solve a particular problem. Learning data structures",
                "topics": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ARRAYS AND VECTORS",
                        "duration": 7,
                        "subtopics": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Pre-Computations in Array",
                                "homework_id": 1,
                                "assignment_id": 1,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "Pre-Computations",
                                "homework_id": 1,
                                "assignment_id": 2,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "description": "Static and Dynamic Arrays, Pre-Computations, Array Rotations, Sliding Window Technique, Bucketization Technique etc.",
                        "sequence_no": 1,
                        "assessment_id": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ARRAYS AND VECTORS",
                        "duration": 7,
                        "subtopics": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Pre-Computations in Array",
                                "homework_id": 1,
                                "assignment_id": 1,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "Pre-Computations",
                                "homework_id": 1,
                                "assignment_id": 2,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "description": "Static and Dynamic Arrays, Pre-Computations, Array Rotations, Sliding Window Technique, Bucketization Technique etc.",
                        "sequence_no": 1,
                        "assessment_id": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "MATHS",
                        "duration": 7,
                        "subtopics": null,
                        "description": "Modular arithmetic, Combinatorics, Euclid’s Algorithm for GCD, Primality Testing : Sieve of Eratosthenes, Fast Factorization, Catalan Numbers",
                        "sequence_no": 2,
                        "assessment_id": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "OPERATING SYSTEMS",
                "duration": 30,
                "description": "An exhaustive collection of all the must-know concepts of Operating Systems",
                "topics": [
                    {
                        "id": 100,
                        "name": "Threads and Processes",
                        "duration": 4,
                        "subtopics": [
                            {
                                "id": 5,
                                "name": "Basics of Threads and Processes",
                                "homework_id": 100,
                                "assignment_id": 100,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 6,
                                "name": "Inter Process Communication",
                                "homework_id": null,
                                "assignment_id": null,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "description": "Difference b/w Threads and Processes, PCB",
                        "sequence_no": 1,
                        "assessment_id": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "name": "Memory Management",
                        "duration": 3,
                        "subtopics": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "name": "Logical And Physical Memory",
                                "homework_id": 101,
                                "assignment_id": 101,
                                "on_free_trial": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "description": "Logical and Physical Memory, Paging, Fragmentation",
                        "sequence_no": 2,
                        "assessment_id": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Python",
                "duration": 4,
                "description": "Basics of python language.",
                "topics": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Python list",
                        "duration": 1,
                        "subtopics": null,
                        "description": "Basics of python.",
                        "sequence_no": 1,
                        "assessment_id": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

As one can see the topic is getting repeated because of assessment_id. I want it to be structured in form of an array Or array of objects as subtopics are.

Comment: I didn't know postgres can do that, but I think I see the difference: you should use `'assessments', assessments.assesments` instead of `'assessment_id',assessment.id`, like you did wirh the subtopics

Comment: @Turo Thanks it worked, I missed that. Write it as the answer. I will accept it ;)

Comment: Your welcome, glad I learned this! Thanks, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the assessments in the json_build_object as you did with the subtopics:

```
  select courses.course_id as id, courses.course_name as name, courses.course_duration as 
  duration, courses.course_description as description,
  jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_build_object(
          'id',          topics.topic_id,
          'name',        topics.topic_name,
          'duration',    topics.topic_duration,
          'sequence_no',   topics.sequence_no,
          'description', topics.topic_description,
          'subtopics',   subtopic.subtopics,
          'assessments', assessments.assessments
      )
      order by topics.topic_id
  ) topics
  ...
```